# PHPUnit mock parent protected method, which is owerriden

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

How could I test method Bar::foo?

```
class Foo {
    protected function foo() {
        // Do something
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    protected function foo() {
        parent::foo();
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

I need to mock Foo::foo and not to have

```
Fatal error: Access level to Bar::foo() must be public (as in class Foo)...
```

??

Comment: Are you sure that `Foo::foo` is protected? The error message is telling you otherwise. `Foo::foo` is public there, which means `Bar` is breaking the inherited contract. A child class can turn a `protected` method into a `public` one (increasing visibility), but it can't restrict the visibility (ie `public` to `protected` is not allowed). Either way: use a reflection class to make the method public and you're set

Comment: It becomes public when I'm trying to mock it.

Comment: What class/object are you mocking, where and how? `Bar` or `Foo`, and how are you changing the visibility to `public`? show the code

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to mock `Foo::foo` to test your method.  The fact that it calls the parent's `foo` method is an implementation detail.  You don't need to make sure that a `Bar` object calls any of `Foo`'s methods.  The only thing that you would assert is that `Bar` is an instance of `Foo`.

From your example, you don't even need to explicitly test `Bar::foo` either because it is a protected method.  If `Bar::foo` is complicated enough that you think that you need to write a test for it.  Consider refactoring it to its own class and using the Strategy pattern for `Bar`.

You don't want your tests checking whether or not internal methods are called.  This makes refactoring your classes much more difficult.  Your test should pass if you were to copy all the lines from `Foo::foo` into `Bar::foo`.  It isn't good coding practice.  But tests don't ensure good code.  They ensure that code works correctly.